# New to Angular - setup in eclipse does not work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse

Trying to write (copy) a test Angular project in eclipse. Have the the three files from Angular website https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController in my eclipse project(which I created as static web project then converted to Angular project). Does not display values correctly. Clear works. Alert etc don't.

Can someone please advise?!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy this link into your head tag:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>`

also may I ask you why you are using Eclipse and not a more simple editor like notepad++ or sublime? I never heard of an angular.js programmer who uses Eclipse.

Comment: Hi Matan, Thanks for the reply. But that did not work. I am in the process of getting sublime - thanks for the suggestion. Nagasimha Iyengar

Comment: If it's a problem with AngularJS Eclipse, please tell me what is the problem. What do you mean with " Does not display values correctly. Clear works. Alert etc don't.", completion, hover, validation doesn't work inside JS Editor or HTML Editor  for Angular expression?

Answer (score 0):

Just go the link [here](http://tutorialbasics.blogspot.com/2015/10/simple-angularjs-application-in-eclispe.html) and follow the steps in your eclipse. But in my eclipse given CDN in this link does not work. So I changed the CDN server to `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>` .It is work well. May be OK.